# Meaning of Msiexec.exe switches

Tags: windows-installer

I have problems installing .msi files. Looking in the registry I've found the following entry:

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "%1" %*
```

I understand the /i swhitch as per the [this](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html) site, but I don't understand what is the meaning of the rest

```
"%1" %*
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%1` is a placeholder for the .msi file to be executed, `%*` is a placeholder for optional arguments passed to the .msi file.

An example how this could expand:

```
"c:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "c:\foo\bar.msi" INSTALLDIR="c:\program files\foo"
```

Here is a [list of available placeholders](https://superuser.com/a/473602).